# What are these localhosts accessing Apache virtualhost?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

In my server-status page I see a lot of requests from localhost. what are these for? are they actually doing anything?

```
201-0   -   0/0/327 .   0.94    28653   0   0.0 0.00    99.83   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
202-0   -   0/0/140 .   1.65    28333   0   0.0 0.00    52.80   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
203-0   -   0/0/359 .   3.15    28425   0   0.0 0.00    88.87   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
204-0   -   0/0/353 .   4.16    28861   0   0.0 0.00    150.89  ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
205-0   -   0/0/382 .   0.18    28275   0   0.0 0.00    86.17   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
206-0   -   0/0/242 .   1.19    28586   0   0.0 0.00    119.88  ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
207-0   -   0/0/260 .   1.06    28475   0   0.0 0.00    90.53   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
208-0   -   0/0/381 .   4.92    28644   0   0.0 0.00    57.20   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
209-0   -   0/0/172 .   0.81    28273   0   0.0 0.00    101.78  ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
210-0   -   0/0/277 .   1.76    28695   0   0.0 0.00    70.73   ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
211-0   -   0/0/776 .   6.57    20491   0   0.0 0.00    211.93  ::1 domain.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal result of apache doing normal things to itself. You can read all about it here:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

The super short and way over simplified version: The connections /requests are called Internal Dummy Connections and are a result of apache handling its own threads.